# adding a tracking pixel in order confirmation page

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, ecommerce-tracking

I have received a tracking pixel from one of our advertising company, and they asked me to place that code in my order confirmation page.

first of all can some one tell me where is the order confirmation file located in magento?

And 2nd if i need to get "order ID" value and "Amount" of the order then what to use in this pixel.

```
<img src="https://www.emjcd.com/u?AMOUNT=AMOUNT&CID=7777777&OID=OID&TYPE=5555555&CURRENCY=GBP&METHOD=IMG" height="1" width="20"/>
```

you can get more information here: http://www.pricerunner.co.uk/about/sales-tracking-instructions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You will need to copy your base template file from**

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml
```

To your ultimo theme path

```
app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/checkout
```

You can put below code in your success.phtml file

```
<?php    
    $order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
    $grandTotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
    $orderCurrency = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
?>

<img src="https://www.emjcd.com/u?AMOUNT=<?php echo $grandTotal; ?>&CID=7777777&OID='<?php echo $order_id;?>'&TYPE=5555555&CURRENCY=<?php echo $orderCurrency; ?>&METHOD=IMG" height="1" width="20"/>
```

Comment: Hi @akhilesh thanks for your help but "we need to alter the <AMOUNT> and  <OID> (highlighted below) to pull in this information from your site. So you'll need to find out which macros create this information and then enter them here."

Comment: did you tried this code? It didn't work for you? I think it will do same as mention in your url http://www.pricerunner.co.uk/about/sales-tracking-instructions.html

Comment: i have tried this code but i cant see this in my success page html, when placed order on front end.

Comment: did you clear your magento cache after changing the file?

Comment: also enabled your template path hints and place order so you will get idea if your success.phtml file path is correct and it is not calling from somewhere else.

Comment: yes i did clear the cache, how to enable template path hints?

Comment: http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: these are the html path showing in my hint: frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml    ,frontend/base/default/template/catalog/msrp/popup.phtml         ,frontend/base/default/template/meanbee/ordershare/ordershare.phtml         which of these templates i place my code? Thanks

Comment: yes, now place an order from frontend and see from where your success.phtml path coming. if path is coming from correct place where you put above code. on success page ctrl+u and check source code and check if above img src code exist or not.

Comment: yes these template path i found on order confirmation page. can you tell where is the success.phtml coming from? i could not found any template on success page with name success.phtml, so i think it is using ordershare.phtml instead.

Comment: that means you are using custom order share module and it is overriding success.phtml file with ordershare.phtml file. you will just need to put my code in ordershare.phtml file and it will work for you.

Comment: yes it was and now it works there.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the rwd theme, it's in
     /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/success.phtml

The order object isn't present on the confirmation page - it's already unloaded by this stage. So you could write a module to hook into the order save function, but if you need a quick fix you could load the last order id using something like (in success.phtml):

```
$lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/order'); 
$order->load($lastOrderId);
$_totalData =$order->getData(); 
$_sub = $_totalData['subtotal'];
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, but how to use this code togather with above one?

Comment: i am using ultimo, but i cant find success.phtml any where in my theme.

Comment: Hi, you need to find /app/design/frontend/base/default/teamplte/checkout/success.phtml and copy to your ultimo theme path, as mention below in Akhilesh's answer. You can do print_r($order) to view the order array (but this may be large)

Answer (score 0):

Magento v2.1.x

Here's all what you need with some extra values as well

```
<?php
$merchantid = "<ID>";

$objectManager  =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderId        = $block->getOrderId();
$order          = $objectManager
                    ->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')
                    ->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$subtotal       = $order->getSubtotal();
$discount       = $order->getDiscountAmount(); 
$affiliateTotal = ($subtotal + $discount);

$ordered_items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
$skulist = '';
$pricelist = '';
$quantitylist = '';

$last_index = array_search(end($ordered_items), $ordered_items, true);
foreach($ordered_items as $index => $item){
    $delimiter    = $index === $last_index ? '' : ',';
    $skulist      .= $item->getSku() . $delimiter;
    $quantitylist .= ceil($item->getQtyOrdered()) . $delimiter;
    $pricelist    .= ($item->getProduct()->getFinalPrice() - ($item->getDiscountAmount() / $item->getQtyOrdered())) . $delimiter;
}
$couponcodes = $order->getCouponCode();

$currency = $order->getOrderCurrencyCode();
//render pixel below
?>
<img src="https://www.emjcd.com/u?tracking=<?php echo $orderId ?>&amp;amount=<?php echo $affiliateTotal ?>&amp;transtype=sale&amp;merchantID=<?php echo $merchantid ?>&amp;couponcode=<?php echo $couponcodes ?>&amp;skulist=<?php echo $skulist ?>&amp;quantitylist=<?php echo $quantitylist ?>&amp;pricelist=<?php echo $pricelist ?>&amp;currency=<?php echo $currency ?>&amp;v=2.0" width="1" height="1">
```